# How do I get the tag of a class and an ID in a single div?

Tags: html, css, class, tags

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="row" id="above-footer-bg">
```

How am I going combine both class and id
so I could use it to edit in my stylesheet?

Comment: If the answer wasn't clear or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1):

The selector prefix for id is `#` and for class `.`

Combine them one after the other without a space

```css
#above-footer-bg.row{
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="above-footer-bg">test</div>
```